# How to write below query in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a table and there are two columns.

| user_id | to_user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 102 |
| 102 | 101 |
| 101 | 105 |

In the above table, 1 and 2 rows of users are like each other I want to remove 2 rows.

Here is my code.

```
$query = \App\Models\MyMatch::query();
$query->whereHas('users')->whereHas('tousers')
    ->select('my_matches.*')->distinct()
    ->where('user_id', '!=', 'to_user_id');
$records = $query->get();
```

In the above code, I got total 3 rows

I want only a total of 2 rows 1 and 3

So, how can I write a query for it

Comment: AFAIK `->where('user_id', '!=', 'to_user_id');`  does not work, you are comparing the `user_id` column to the value `'to_user_id'`. I think you need `->whereColumn('user_id', '!=', 'to_user_id');` maybe `!=` needs to be `<`, but don't have enough context to know at this point. Currently it always renders true

Answer (score 0):

```
$records = \App\Models\MyMatch::whereHas('users')->whereHas('tousers')
->where(function($query) {
    $query->where('user_id', '!=', 'to_user_id')
        ->orWhere(function($query) {
            $query->where('user_id', '<', 'to_user_id');
        });
})
->distinct()
->get();
```

or use a subquery :

```
$subquery = DB::table('my_matches')
                ->select('user_id', 'to_user_id')
                ->whereColumn('user_id', '>', 'to_user_id')
                ->toSql();

$records = \App\Models\MyMatch::whereHas('users')->whereHas('tousers')
    ->whereNotExists(function($query) use ($subquery) {
        $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                ->from(DB::raw("($subquery) as sub"))
                ->whereRaw('my_matches.user_id = sub.to_user_id and my_matches.to_user_id = sub.user_id');
    })
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$query = \App\Models\MyMatch::query();
$query->whereHas('users')->whereHas('tousers')
    ->select('my_matches.*')
    ->where('user_id', '!=', 'to_user_id')
    ->groupBy('to_user_id')
    ->havingRaw('COUNT(*) = 1');
$records = $query->get();
```